# RMAN: restore not done; all files read only, offline, excluded, or already restored

Tags: backup, restore, rman, oracle-19c, archive-log

I did a hot RMAN backup of a server running Oracle 19c database, then moved the backup to a new server.

This is the backupscript

```
BACKUP AS compressed BACKUPSET INCREMENTAL LEVEL=0 FORMAT 'Prod_Full_DB_%u_%s_%p' DATABASE plus archivelog;
```

When I completed the restore, I faced this error

```
SQL> RECOVER DATABASE;
ORA-00283: recovery session canceled due to errors
ORA-01610: recovery using the BACKUP CONTROLFILE option must be done


SQL> RECOVER DATABASE USING BACKUP CONTROLFILE UNTIL CANCEL;
ORA-00279: change 8922136743 generated at 03/24/2024 04:19:33 needed for thread
1
ORA-00289: suggestion : /u03/archives/1_65472_1115909325.dbf
ORA-00280: change 8922136743 for thread 1 is in sequence #65472


Specify log: {<RET>=suggested | filename | AUTO | CANCEL}

ORA-00308: cannot open archived log '/u03/archives/1_65472_1115909325.dbf'
ORA-27037: unable to obtain file status
Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
Additional information: 7
```

I solved this error by manually transferring the archives to the server. I also realized that the archive which was causing problem was made DURING the backup process.

After the restore was completed I did some searching, and found a way to restore archives from the backup pieces:

```
run {
allocate channel t1 type disk;
set archivelog destination to '/u04/';
restore archivelog until sequence 65460;
release channel t1;
}
```

however, I am facing this error

```
archived log for thread 1 with sequence 1 is already on disk as file /u01/archives/1_1_1164473680.dbf
archived log for thread 1 with sequence 2 is already on disk as file /u01/archives/1_2_1164473680.dbf
restore not done; all files read only, offline, excluded, or already restored
```

**I guess this might be because the database has already been restored.**

any changes I should make when I am taking the backup, as the archive which was causing an issue, was made while the backup was being taken.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're *not* using a Recovery Catalog.
If that's the case, then you get *one and only one* shot at restoring/recovering your database.  After that, you have to tear the whole thing down and start all over again again (restricted mode, drop database, all that).

Why?  Because the "structural" information about all the DataFiles, Log Files, etc., is stored *in the ControlFile* and, as soon as you perform a Recovery, that information is *overwritten*.
A Recovery Catalog (which is little more than a separate database with specific schemas in it) acts as a "safe copy" of all that information and allows you to attempt restores repeatedly.

Since you're using the recover `until cancel` method, you should be able to recover up to the point you *have* logs, then stop and open your database with `resetlogs`, thereby creating a new incarnation of it (and yes; a Recovery Catalog will handle *those* perfectly as well).

Comment: at which step should I use recovery catalog?

Comment: You create your Recovery Catalog [database], then register your actual database with it, then you can start your recovery activity.  Refer to https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/bradv/managing-recovery-catalog.html#GUID-2491887B-D9AC-48BE-914D-CB0341A77057

Comment: Is this the only way to restore a hot backup?

Comment: No, you /can/ do it with /only/ the ControlFile, etc., but ONLY ONCE.  
After you do a restore and then the User says "Oh; can we go back 10 minutes more?", it's far, far easier to do so with a Recovery Catalog.